# Ajax:Calendar - content of calender is small that I cannot see all the days

Tags: css, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-ajax

I am trying to use `Ajax Calendar v3.0.20820.6783`  for my `Asp.net-3.5` project.
It works well but I have a CSS issue that I couldn't manage to fix.

The actual calendar size is small, so it is not being displayed well as to be seen below, Saturday and Sunday is missing for some reason. No CSS applied on it now, it came like that by default. Increasing width-height in CSS did not fix, only the white-background size changed when I did.

[image]

Also, then I press the month, it is seen like the picture below:

[image]

How can I fix it? Thanks for any ideas.

The code to create the calendar is here:

```
<table>
      <tr>
         <td>
           <asp:Label ID="labelallowto" runat="server" Text="AllowedTo:"> </asp:Label> 
         </td>
         <td>
            <div>  
               <asp:TextBox ID="txtAllowedTo" runat="server" autocomplete="off"></asp:TextBox>  
               <cc1:CalendarExtender ID="Calendar1" BehaviorID="behaviorIDAllowFrom" FirstDayOfWeek="Monday" PopupButtonID="imgPopup" runat="server" TargetControlID="txtAllowedFrom" Format="dd/MM/yyyy"> </cc1:CalendarExtender>  
            </div>  
         </td>
</tr></table>
```

Regards.

EDIT: when I increase width, it is seen like that for example:

[image]

Only background gets larger.

Answer (score 0):

Adding a CssClass with those below fixed it:

ASPX:

```
<cc1:CalendarExtender ID="Calendar1" CssClass="cal_Theme" BehaviorID="behaviorIDAllowFrom" FirstDayOfWeek="Monday" PopupButtonID="imgPopup" runat="server" TargetControlID="txtAllowedFrom" Format="dd/MM/yyyy"> </cc1:CalendarExtender>
```

CSS:

```
 .cal_Theme .ajax__calendar_container th {
 padding: 0px;}
 .cal_Theme .ajax__calendar_container td {
 padding: 0px;}
 .cal_Theme .ajax__calendar_month {
  padding-bottom: 3px;
  margin-top: -3.5px}
```